# AWS custom metric alarm to monitor DB connections

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to create an custom metric alarm to monitor my DB connections from instance. Command using is "netstat -an | grep :5432"

Can someone help me on this

Thanx

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Where exactly is your problem in this question ?

Comment: I tried to send data to log group and applied filter pattern and made custom metric to create alarm. 
can you suggest me any other good way to monitor number of database connections from ec2 instance.